# I want to add rows and locking again

Tags: jquery

At first doing the normal error-free locking.I want to add rows pressure locking again.
Where might errors ?
I would be happy if you look at the example.
add row > not works [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmetsadri/SDctG/)

HTML

```
<table class="color"  cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" id="myTable">
<tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Lock/Unlock</td>
    <td>Lock/Unlock</td>
    <td>Lock/Unlock</td>
</tr>


<tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <select name="select" id="selecta">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1" selected>Lock</option>
            <option value="2">Unlock</option>
        </select>
    </td>

    <td>
        <input name="textfield" type="text" class="textfield" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="textfield" type="text" class="textfield" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="textfield" type="text" class="textfield" value="1" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
        <select name="select" id="selecta">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1" selected>Lock</option>
            <option value="2">Unlock</option>
        </select>
    </td>

    <td>
        <input name="textfield" type="text" class="textfield" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="textfield" type="text" class="textfield" value="1" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="textfield" type="text" class="textfield" value="1" />
    </td>
</tr>

   <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" style="text-align: left;">
                <input type="button" id="addrow" value="Add Rows" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tfoot>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.row').each(function () {
        var $dropdown = $(this).find('#selecta'),
            $textfield = $(this).find('.textfield');
        $dropdown.change(function () {
            if ($dropdown.val() != '1') {
                $textfield.removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $textfield.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
            }
        }).trigger('change'); // added trigger to calculate initial state
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
            var counter = 0;

            $("#addrow").on("click", function () {

                counter = $('#myTable tr').length - 2;

                var newRow = $('<tr class="row">');
                var cols = "";

                cols += '  <td>1</td><td><select name="select" id="selecta"><option value="0"></option><option value="1" selected>Lock</option><option value="2">Unlock</option></select> </td><td><input name="textfield" type="text" class="textfield" value="1" /></td><td><input name="textfield" type="text" class="textfield" value="1" /></td><td> <input name="textfield" type="text" class="textfield" value="1" /></td>';

                cols += '<td><input type="button"  value="x" ></td>';
                newRow.append(cols);
                if (counter == 4) $('#addrow').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
                $("table.color").append(newRow);
                counter++;
            });

    $("table.color").on("click", ".buttons", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        calculateGrandTotal();

        counter -= 1
        $('#addrow').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "Add Rows");
    });


});
```

I want to add rows pressure locking again.

Comment: What is 'pressure locking'?

Comment: sory little english. I have mentioned in the error demo links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to use `duplicate IDs`. I have therefore changed `#selecta` to `.selecta` in your markup and code.

Since you're adding rows dynamically, you have to use event delegation when binding the 'row locking' handler as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change','.selecta',function() {
        $(this).closest('.row').find('.textfield')
        .prop('disabled', (this.value == '1'))
        .val( this.value == 1 ? '' : this.value );
    });
    $('.selecta').change();// added trigger to calculate initial state
});
```

Then once a new row is added, you do have to trigger change on the select in that row:

```
newRow.find('.selecta').change();
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/SDctG/4/)

I prefer to manipulate the `disabled` property instead of having to add and remove the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: +1 but a small comment: The static rows don't get initialized as before. Maybe because you call trigger('change') on $(document)?